# Dynamically Allocate Pointers to Arrays

Tags: c, memory-management

I have been searching and trying to run simple test programs, but I still can't figure this one out:

Is it possible, in pure C, to allocate a pointer dynamically that points to an array?

What I'd like to accomplish is to copy a string to a char[20] array, but the number of these char arrays is unknown.  The variable I declare is

```
char (*value)[20]
```

From what I understand, this is a pointer to an array of 20 chars, which is what I need

However, how do I allocate memory for this variable?  How can I do it dynamically in which I don't know the number of char[20] that will exist?  Am I way off in thinking this is the solution to my design problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `to copy a string to a char[20] array` - one string to one array? Why do you need many arrays then?

Comment: I phrased that poorly.  What's exactly happening is I'm receiving netlink messages from the Kernel.  Every time I receive a message, it returns a string.  I want to store that string (of length 20), but the number of times the kernel will send a message is unknown.  Therefore the need for dynamic allocation of a known-length array... if that makes anymore sense.

Comment: `allocate a pointer that points to an array` - what do you mean? You allocate memory, not pointer. So what memory do you need? For pointer or for array?

Comment: `value = malloc(number_of_strings * sizeof *value);` like all `malloc`s, basically.

Comment: @Daniel `number of strings` is unknown at the start.  So for the first string, I'd have `value = malloc(sizeof(*value))`, as you suggest, but the next time around, how and where do I allocate additional memory for the next `char[20]` array?

Comment: Use `realloc`? `char (*temp)[20] = realloc(value, new_number * sizeof *value); if (!temp) { /* handle allocation failure or die */ } value = temp;`

Comment: @justynnuff It looks like you need *FIFO*. There is example in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO. But if need to store only, then look answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array that grows in size, you have no other choice but dynamically allocate memory, that way for example, provided you know all your strings will have *exactly* 20 characters :

```
#define STR_SIZE 20
char* values = NULL;
int nb = 0;

...

// Called every time a string is received
// Here valuesPtr is a char** since we want to change values
void appendStr(char** valuesPtr, int* nb, char* string) {
    if (*nb == 0) {  // First item
        *valuesPtr = malloc(STR_SIZE);
    } else {  // The size of the array changes : realloc it
        *valuesPtr = realloc(*valuesPtr, STR_SIZE * (*nb + 1));
    }

    if (*valuesPtr == NULL) {  // Something went wrong !
        perror("malloc/realloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Copy the new string at the right place
    memcpy(*valuesPtr + STR_SIZE * (*nb), string, STR_SIZE);
    *nb++;
}
```

In the rest of the code, accessing the nth string is done this way :

```
values + (STR_SIZE * nb)
```

Comment: I'm a n00b, so I can't +1, but this is the solution I'm looking for.  I thought there would be a more efficient way of using a pointer to a character array instead of just a pointer to a pointer, but I suppose not.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use an array of strings:

```
char *strings[256]; // or use malloc/realloc but 256 pointers is OK
int cnt = 0;
void add_string(const char *s) {
   strings[cnt] = (char*)malloc(strlen(s)+1); // or 21
   cnt++;
   // you can also do circular buffers
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but the way I see it is this: I know how many characters my strings contain, but not how many strings there will be.  This solution assumes you know how many strings there will be (256), but not how many characters are in each.

Comment: this is just to show you that you could use a circular buffer or dynamic array of `char *`, and you don't really need an array of `char[20]`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that writes a constant string to the array of arrays pointed to by value `num_arrays` times.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(int num_arrays)
{
  const char* s = "A string";
  char (*value)[20];
  value = (char (*)[20]) malloc(sizeof(*value) * num_arrays);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++) {
    strncpy(value[i],s,20);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", value[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but `num_arrays` isn't known, so I can't `malloc` that entire chunk of memory at the start.  I think I need to `malloc(sizeof(*value))` for the first char[20] value, and use some sort of pointer arithmetic to `malloc` another 20 char chunk of memory later.  But I'm not sure what to do.  Something like `value+sizeof(*value) = malloc(sizeof(*value))` but this doesn't work.